# Only allow the POST method for a specific file in a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, http-headers

I have one file that should only be accessible via the POST method.

```
/var/www/folder/index.php
```

The document root is `/var/www/` and `index.php` is nested inside a folder.

Version of Apache is: 2.4.4.
My configurations are as follows:

```
<Directory "/var/www/folder">
    <Files "index.php">
        order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        <LimitExcept POST>
            Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I visit my server at `127.0.0.1/folder` but I can GET and POST the file just like normal.

I've also tried reversing the order, `order allow,deny`, require, limitexcept and limit.

How can I only allow POST requests to be processed by one file in a folder?

Comment: A rewrite condition would be indeed more efficient but less secure due to the use of Regex which can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`Require`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive:

```
<Directory "/var/www/folder">
    <Files "index.php">
        Require method POST
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

However, since that's part of the authorization section, you may want to try this instead:

```
<Directory "/var/www/folder">
    <Files "index.php">
        <LimitExcept POST>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 4):

If your apache config tricks don't work, you could do it in the index.php itself. At the top of the file add something like thisthis:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") {
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    print("Forbidden");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I would prefer to do this at this at the apache level. If this were a PHP issue, I'd post this on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` family of access control directives have been deprecated in favour of [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html).

This may actually be the reason that you existing config is not working, as any conflicting `Require` directives will take precedence of your config (which is still supported by means of [mod_access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html), but these directives will be removed in a future version).

Since you a using the 2.4 family, you should also be using the new style directives. I have tested the below configuration on 2.4.4 and it works as desired:

```
<Directory "/var/www/folder">
    Require all granted
    <Files "index.php">
        <LimitExcept POST>
            Require all denied
        </LimitExcept>
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Jack's observation that you could use the `Require method` directive is also correct and arguably a more 2.4-like way of doing this.